# mutable with const pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, mutable

If I use `mutable` with `const` pointer like this:

```
class Test
{
    public:
    mutable const int* ptr; // OK
};
```

It's working fine.

But, If I use like this :

```
class Test
{
    public:
    mutable int * const ptr; // Error
};
```

An error :

```
prog.cpp:6:25: error: const 'ptr' cannot be declared 'mutable'
     mutable int * const ptr;
                         ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:11:7: error: use of deleted function 'Test::Test()'
  Test t;
       ^
prog.cpp:3:7: note: 'Test::Test()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Test
       ^
prog.cpp:3:7: error: uninitialized const member in 'class Test'
prog.cpp:6:25: note: 'int* const Test::ptr' should be initialized
     mutable int * const ptr;
```

Why does compiler give an error in second case?

Comment: What does an error message say? It is probably worth reading.

Comment: @VTT http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/PWB4ti

Comment: *Edit your question* to include build errors. Copy-pasted verbatim, as text, in full and complete.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 7):

> `const int * ptr;`

The first is a *pointer to constant* data, which means you can change the *pointer* and where it points to, but you can't change the data it points to.

> `int * const ptr;`

The second is a *constant-pointer to non-constant* data, which means you must initialize the pointer in your constructor(s) and then you can't make it point anywhere else. The data it points to can be modified though.

The `mutable` part in both cases applies to the *pointer*, the actual *member variable*, not the data it points to. And since the variable can't be both `mutable` and `const`ant at the same time you should get an error message for that.

Answer (score 5):

The 2nd case causes error because `mutable` and `const` can't be mixed; [`mutable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) can only be used with non-const data member.

> applies to non-static class members of non-reference non-const type and specifies that the member does not affect the externally visible state of the class (as often used for mutexes, memo caches, lazy evaluation, and access instrumentation). mutable members of const class instances are modifiable.

BTW the following code causes the same error.

```
class Test
{
    public:
    mutable const int x; // Error;
    mutable int const x; // ditto;
};
```

The 1st case is fine, because `const int*` is not a `const` pointer, but a pointer to `const`. That means it's fine to modify the pointer itself, and you can mark it `mutable`. (But you can't modify the pointee.)

BTW `const` pointer to `const` (e.g. `mutable const int* const ptr;`) causes the same error too.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Test
{
    const int* ptr;
};
```

Translation: *"The structure has a member. The member is a pointer. The pointer points to an integer which may not be mutated via the pointer."*

The pointer itself may be mutated though, to point to a different `const int`.

It's probably simpler if we pick a non-reference type, so you can separate the types of the member (in your example a pointer), from the type of the pointed-to object.

```
struct Test1
{
    int value;
};
```

Now, adding the `mutable` keyword to get

```
struct Test2
{
    mutable int value;
};
```

just means we're allowed to mutate the member *even when the structure itself is otherwise const*.

In other words, all of this is OK in both cases:

```
Test1 a { 123 };
Test2 b { 123 };

// now mutate the object through a non-const reference
a.value = 42;
b.value = 42;
```

but this is different:

```
const Test1& ca = a;
ca.value = 69; // NO, a member of a const object is const

const Test2& cb = b;
cb.value = 69; // OK, a mutable member of a const object
```

So, now that we understand how mutable is being applied, the consider the problematic line:

```
mutable int * const ptr;
```

This is saying that `ptr` is *both* mutable (able to be mutated even when the object it's a member of is otherwise const) *and* const (not able to be mutated even when the object it's a member of is otherwise non-const).

The two are obviously contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

The [bugs.eclipse.org](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84479) say's:

> The mutable specifier can be applied only to names of class data
>   members (9.2)  and **cannot be applied to names declared const or
>   static, and cannot be applied  to reference members.**